# is it possible to map people to transcript with AWS transcribe?

Tags: amazon-web-services, speaker, transcription, amazon-transcribe

I need to use some transcription service to transcribe speech. I recieve very good results with AWS transcribe. But i also need to know which person says what. Is this possible with AWS transcribe? I cannot find anything about this.

ex. what i get now is

Speaker 1: hello how are you?

Speaker 2: I am good how are you?

Speaker 1: fine...

What I would like to get is to be able to know who is  speaker 1 and two. for example by uploading  samples

Bob: hello how are you?

Alice: I am good how are you?

Bob: fine...

is this possible with AWS?

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches:

- Use multiple channels (eg left & right audio) to separate speakers. This is good for telephone calls with two distinct speakers. See: [Transcribing multi-channel audio - Amazon Transcribe](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/latest/dg/channel-id.html)
- Identifying speakers with diarization, see: [Identifying speakers (speaker diarization) - Amazon Transcribe](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/latest/dg/diarization.html)

These will identify *separate* speakers. However, you cannot upload a "sample" and then identify the *specific* speaker.